# First Analysis of Dataset in Python - Multiple Criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I am very new to python and am trying to do my first project.
I have downloaded the pandas package and use that to analyse my datasets.

I essentially have a marketing campaign to analyse which has the following data columns in CSV format:

1. Email address
2. Age
3. Male / Female
4. Location
5. Response (Y/N)

What I would like to do is for each combination of different Ages, different Male Female / Locations, work out the average response rate i.e. Y/(Y+N)

I want the code to be dynamic so that I can analyse different marketing campaigns. So that means for one marketing campaign I may have 20 different ages, for another I would have 100 different ages.

I think I can write a code that loops through each of the different combinations so for each different Age, take each different location and each Male / Female. However this is loads of loops which makes it slow. I'm sure there is a better way.

If it was looping like that there would be too many loops:
All the different age options multiplied by 2 (Male & Female) multiplied all the location options

Is there a better way? I'm sure there is but I can't find it?

[This is what the data looks like roughly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVbsK.png)

Comment: Hi. When you ask a question you should add some small sample of data and show us an expected result.

Comment: Thanks Arkadiusz, I've added a sample of the data and the expected result in excel formula

Comment: Do it as text, so that others can work on it. What have you tried so far? You could add that as well...